# Windows IoT Core failes to boot, how to debug

Tags: raspberry-pi3, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I have a number of SD-cards, with Windows IoT Core installed, which has been running in Raspberry Pi 3b for a time, sometimes weeks and sometimes months. They all have some kind of boot issue. Some wont boot at all, I can't even reach the Windows Debug Portal, so I assume that the installation of Windows IoT Core are totally broken. Some boot fine most of the time and sometimes fails with an error [image] which reboots after a couple of seconds and often times manage to boot properly.

I have tried to follow this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/windowsdebugger#raspberry-pi-2-or-3-rpi2-or-rpi3 but when I try to run:
`bcdedit /store c:\EFIESP\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD -debug on`
I get: `An error occurred while attempting to access the specified entry. The system cannot find the file specified.`.

Blue Screens are also pretty common, when they happen the system does not reboot as far as I have seen.

I know that the devices are fine and working, and the SD-cards also seems to be fine, no broken partitions or similar.

How do I find out what went wrong?

Comment: Hi, did you run the command `mkdir C:\EFIESP mountvol C:\EFIESP \?\Volume{ae420040-0000-0000-0000-200000000000}` to create the EFIESP junction?

Comment: As I want to debug a SD-card which doesn't start I have to take the card and plug it into my laptop and run the commands, targeting the drive where the card gets mounted. Is that a problem? The command I run is `bcdedit /store D:/efi/Microsoft/boot/bcd -debug on`, which fails as desribed. Running `bcdedit /store D:/efi/Microsoft/boot/bcd -debug -dbgsettings serial` works.

Comment: You should run the command via [powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/connect-your-device/powershell) connected to the device.

Comment: And if the device doesn't boot properly? And I can't connect to the device?

I never got the mountvol-command as described in the documentation to work. I did `mountvol X: /s` instead and replaced `C:\EFIESP` with `X:\` in the two other commands. And got debugging working on a device that boots.